# sbrk(0) value getting increased after calling printf

Tags: c, gcc, malloc

I am trying to write my own malloc implementation, following an online course. Issue I am facing is that i always get segmentation fault, and when i tried to debug it always point to printf statement, which is just a string. After further investigation i found the value for sbrk(0) always increase after printf gets called.

I am not sure but i think my malloc implementation overwrites some memory space that printf might be using. But is it possible for printf to be there.

The program works fine when there is no printf.

I am using sbrk(size) to increase the size of heap.

Eg. heap before calling printf was 0x604000 to 0x605000 and after calling it was  0x604000 to 0x626000

Comment: You should probably provide a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/). Have you tried using gdb to debug the issue?

Comment: It's quite possible for `printf()` to be using a `malloc()` that uses `sbrk()`, so you could run into problems — `printf()` won't readily use your `malloc()`.  You could try outputting a character to the file stream before calling your code; that would probably trigger the memory allocation and save it interfering with your `malloc()`.  Otherwise, don't call `printf()` inside your `malloc()`.

Comment: Since your code is not the only code using `sbrk()`, you will have to design your allocation system to handle a discontiguous set of blocks of raw memory.  It's quite fun!

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler ... I called printf() before calling my code and now it works fine... I'll definitely now try to handle discontiguous blocks of memory.

Comment: @paulotorrens ... Yes i used gdb to debug it... Issue was that i expected only my code to be allocating and deallocating memory chunks, didn't expect printf would be using heap too.

Comment: From what I know, macOS's `malloc` doesn't use `brk` nor `sbrk` and these functions are only emulated on macOS (though I may be wrong)... I would avoid these functions and use `mmap` on Unix systems (that's what macOS does). `sbrk` and `brk` seem to be mostly legacy functions.

Comment: Exact Same problem I encounter here.  Printf is overwriting on my heap memory created by my own malloc as well! After removing printfs , it works well.