# printf uses sbrk, conflicting with custom memory allocator

Tags: c, linux, memory, sbrk

Hi I have Written a memory allocator, and works perfectly. I use sbrk/brk for page allocation and deallocation. 
But it all breaks the moment i start printing information using printfs. Googling shows that - printf internally does use sbrk also. So, another glibc function (printf) making use of sbrk modified heap segment unexpectedly - corrupting the bookkeeping the memory allocator is doing.

Reference : [sbrk(0) value getting increased after calling printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735859/sbrk0-value-getting-increased-after-calling-printf)
basically, any other glibc function using sbrk would break my memory allocator. 
Can you suggest what could be the possible solution to it ?

Pasting the below backtrace showing that printf eventually calls sbrk. Even after printing is done, I see, break pointer never restores to its original point. Shouldnt printf must have restored the break pointer where it was originally in heap segment ? Any alternative to printf in this regard ?

```
(gdb) bt
0  __GI___sbrk (increment=135168) at sbrk.c:40
1  0x00007ffff7e68a99 in __GI___default_morecore (increment=<optimized out>) at morecore.c:47
2  0x00007ffff7e64297 in sysmalloc (nb=nb@entry=592, av=av@entry=0x7ffff7fb2c40 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:2480
3  0x00007ffff7e657b3 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7fb2c40 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=576) at malloc.c:4149
4  0x00007ffff7e65f25 in tcache_init () at malloc.c:2995
5  0x00007ffff7e66ba6 in tcache_init () at malloc.c:3050
6  __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=1024) at malloc.c:3050
7  0x00007ffff7e4f85c in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x7ffff7fb3760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at filedoalloc.c:101
8  0x00007ffff7e5f0b2 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7fb3760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at libioP.h:904
9  0x00007ffff7e5e198 in _IO_new_file_overflow (f=0x7ffff7fb3760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, ch=-1) at fileops.c:752
10 0x00007ffff7e5cbd5 in _IO_new_file_xsputn (n=13, data=<optimized out>, f=0x7ffff7fb3760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at libioP.h:904
11 _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7fb3760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=<optimized out>, n=13) at fileops.c:1204
12 0x00007ffff7e44e10 in __vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7fb3760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x555555557334 "\nPage Size = %zu Bytes\n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffdcc0,
mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=0) at ../libio/libioP.h:904
13 0x00007ffff7e308d8 in __printf (format=<optimized out>) at printf.c:33
14 0x000055555555677d in mm_print_memory_usage () at mm.c:613
15 0x00005555555552a9 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf18) at testapp.c:64
```

Comment: This is not possible; `sbrk()` is used by the libc memory allocator internally, so many libc functions use it implicitly. Either do not use libc at all, or do your memory allocations with `malloc()` or `mmap()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Ctx:

> This is not possible; `sbrk()` is used by the libc memory allocator internally, so many libc functions use it implicitly. Either do not use libc at all, or do your memory allocations with `malloc()` or `mmap()`.

is correct. You can only use `sbrk` if you don't use `malloc`, and you can't know if you use `malloc` because unless documented otherwise by the implementation, anything in libc might do so.

If your libc supports replacing `malloc` (note: most do) then you can write a full `malloc` replacement (this includes all `malloc`-family functions, not just `malloc` itself) that either don't use `sbrk`, or that cooperate with your use of it, and then you're free to use it. However otherwise, you simply can't use `sbrk`.

Note also that in some environments, including frequently with position-independent executables (PIE), `sbrk` will have little or no memory to work with and will frequently fail after only a few allocations or after none at all, because of running into memory mapped for something else. The whole concept of `sbrk` is backwards and should not be used at all in modern code. For some allocator strategies, it may make sense as one choice of backend, with `mmap` or something else also used. But it should never be the sole way your allocator obtains new memory, and in my opinion it's not really useful to support it at all. `mmap` is better in almost all ways.